# Qu'elle peut/pouvait rester

Tags: temps-grammatical, imparfait, concordance-des-temps

Est-ce que le mot « pouvoir » doit être à l'imparfait dans cette phrase?

> Au commencement, Paul a dit qu’elle peut (pouvait) rester pour deux heures, mais plus tard il permet à Emily de rester pour une plus longue période de temps.

Answer (score 5):

La phrase correcte serait :
Au commencement, Paul a dit qu'elle pouvait rester deux heures, mais plus tard il a permis à Emily de rester pour une plus longue période.
Détails :

- la concordance des temps : toute la phrase se déroule dans un temps passé, donc il ne peut pas y avoir de présent narratif dans la même phrase : "a dit", "pouvait", "a permis"
- pour une plus longue période : inutile d'ajouter "de temps", c'est sous-entendu dans le mot "période". On peut même se contenter de "rester plus longtemps".